# how to create multiple rectangle on gmaps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to create multiple rectangle on gmaps but I don't know where must I put the code.

This is my sample code

```js
 function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {lat: 37.0924, lng: -119.4179324},
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

 var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large 
        '</div>';
  
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });

    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      bounds: 
      new google.maps.LatLngBounds
  <?php 
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
   
   $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM map");
   $cc=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
   ?>
      (
        new google.maps.LatLng (<?php echo $cc['nelat']; ?>, <?php echo $cc['nelng']; ?>),
  new google.maps.LatLng (<?php echo $cc['swlat']; ?>, <?php echo $cc['swlng']; ?>),
        ),

      
    });
   rectangle.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, rectangle);
    });
  }
```

```css
    #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rectangles</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAogXD-AHrsmnWinZIyhRORJ84bgLwDPpg&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In that snippet only show 1 rectangle. If I want to add other rectangle where must I put the code? Example I want to show 5 rectangle and at different position. and also give info window for each rectangle

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use array on rectangles and info windows on gmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300234/how-to-use-array-on-rectangles-and-info-windows-on-gmaps)

Comment: What does the data from your database look like?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `map` (
  `map_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nelat` double(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `nelng` double(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `swlat` double(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `swlng` double(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `info` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: INSERT INTO `map` (`map_id`, `nelat`, `nelng`, `swlat`, `swlng`, `info`) VALUES
(2, 44.862416, -78.423774, 44.753911, -78.629774, 'Area 1'),
(4, 45.064525, -79.082954, 44.956401, -79.288954, 'Area 2'),
(5, 44.815674, -77.127387, 44.707081, -77.333387, 'Area 3');

Comment: The code in your comments is database creation code, not what the data reaqired  to create a rectangle on your map would look like. Please [edit] your question to address comments.

Comment: already edit my question, I add my query for getting data from the database. but this only works for 1 data, I need to create multiple rectangles and call it from the database and also need to add info window when rectangles were clicked and will show Area 1, Area 2 Area 3 on that event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a separate rectangle variable:

```js
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 37.0924, lng: -119.4179324},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          bounds: 
          new google.maps.LatLngBounds

          (
            new google.maps.LatLng (37.778261, -119.4179324),new google.maps.LatLng (36.255123, -115.2383485),
            ),

          
        });
        var rectangle2 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          bounds: 
          new google.maps.LatLngBounds

          (
            new google.maps.LatLng (30.778261, -119.4179324),new google.maps.LatLng (29.255123, -115.2383485),
            ),

          
        });
      }
```

```css
    #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rectangles</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAogXD-AHrsmnWinZIyhRORJ84bgLwDPpg&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you it works. but do I always have to create a variable? so if i have 100 data then i must create "var rectangle100" ? can you give me simple code? cz i have alot data and integrated with the database

Comment: That's the only way I know how to do it. If you're looking to make it dynamic with a database I'm sure it's possible but unsure the best way to approach that myself.